# Using ICEpdf "inside" java program

Tags: java, pdf, icepdf

We have created a program as a uni assignement and wish to use ICEpdf or some other pdf viewer for java.

We have created different tabs, and in one the user can select a pdf file to "upload" and view. The issue is that we wish to make it so that the user can view the pdf inside the application, while ICEpdf currently creates an extra window and displays the pdf separately.

Can this be implemented with the ICEpdf viewer component?

Attached are some images to help explain what is going on.

[image]

**Edit/Update:** Basically ICEpdf needs a jframe, while we need it to run inside the current window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we wanted to do wouldn't/couldn't work, so we just had it open in its own window from a button inside the program.

Answer (score 1):

```
You will need to get border pane in your current window pane   
 /**
     * FXML Controller class
     *
     * @author Sudarshan
     */
    public class PDFFXMLController implements Initializable {    
        private static String pdfPath;
        private SwingController swingController;
        private JComponent viewerPanel;
        @FXML
        private BorderPane borderPane;  
        /**
         * Initializes the controller class.
         */
      @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
         String pdfPathLoad;
        try {
            pdfPathLoad = loadPDF("http://21-04-2017/17854381660C617.pdf");    
            createViewer(borderPane);
            openDocument(pdfPathLoad );
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PDFFXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        }

        private void createViewer(BorderPane borderPane) {
            try {
                SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
                    swingController = new SwingController();
                    swingController.setIsEmbeddedComponent(true);
                    PropertiesManager properties = new PropertiesManager(System.getProperties(),
                            ResourceBundle.getBundle(PropertiesManager.DEFAULT_MESSAGE_BUNDLE));
                    properties.set(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_TOOLBAR_FIT, "false");
                    properties.set(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_TOOLBAR_ROTATE, "false");
                    properties.set(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_TOOLBAR_TOOL, "false");
                    properties.set(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL, "1.25");
                    properties.setBoolean(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_STATUSBAR_VIEWMODE, Boolean.FALSE);
                    properties.set(PropertiesManager.PROPERTY_SHOW_TOOLBAR_PAGENAV, "false");
                    ResourceBundle messageBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(PropertiesManager.DEFAULT_MESSAGE_BUNDLE);
                    new FontPropertiesManager(properties, System.getProperties(), messageBundle);
                    swingController.getDocumentViewController().setAnnotationCallback(
                            new org.icepdf.ri.common.MyAnnotationCallback(swingController.getDocumentViewController()));
                    SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(swingController, properties);
                    viewerPanel = factory.buildViewerPanel();
                    viewerPanel.revalidate();
                    SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
                    swingNode.setContent(viewerPanel);
                    borderPane.setCenter(swingNode);
                    swingController.setToolBarVisible(false);
                    swingController.setUtilityPaneVisible(false);
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            }
        }
        private void openDocument(String document) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    swingController.openDocument(document);
                    viewerPanel.revalidate();
                }
            });
        }
        public String loadPDF(String adresse) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("In load PDf");
            if (!adresse.toLowerCase().endsWith("pdf")) {
                return null;
            }
            String fileName = adresse.substring(adresse.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                    adresse.lastIndexOf("."));
            String suffix = adresse.substring(adresse.lastIndexOf("."),
                    adresse.length());
            File temp = null;
        try {
                InputStream input = new URL(adresse).openStream();
                temp = File.createTempFile(fileName, suffix);
                temp.deleteOnExit();
                Files.copy(input, Paths.get(temp.toURI()),
                        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(PDFFXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
            return temp.getAbsolutePath();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can take a look at the example in ./examples/component/ViewerComponentExample.java in the ICEpdf bundle.  It will demonstrate how to create an embeddable JPanel and setup the keyboard commands.